# Shapefile of Israeli sub-districts

Tags: data, israel

Is anyone aware of freely available shapefile of Israeli sub-districts? The file I found only contained data at the district level.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to add a link to the file that you found to save potential answerers from covering the same ground, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be in OpenData SE.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for and check this out http://www.statsilk.com/maps/download-free-shapefile-maps